# Udevadm doesn't auto trigger after suspended

Tags: systemd, usb, udev, modem

I set up my USB modem with Ubuntu, so that it automatically switches to modem mode every time it suspends and resumes from sleep mode.

Following the instructions from here [1], I was able to do it, but the odd thing is that only when I run the command `sudo udevadm trigger --verbose` manually does the udev rules I wrote work.

Maybe this is some bug about udev or is it due to some configuration that I don't know about yet?
Hope to get help!

[1] [ZTE MF110/MF190 - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ZTE_MF110/MF190#Setup_udev_rules)

Answer (score 0):

Well, because the modem usually takes a while to boot it up (from red light indicator to green light indicator), so I have to attach my command/script as a long running task.

I put my command on a script and insert it to RUN key of the udev rules with at command.

```
ACTION=="add|change|bind", KERNEL=="*", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2000", RUN+="/usr/bin/at -M -f /modem_switch.sh now + 1 minutes"
```

And now it's works as intended.
ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/1017407